# How to save other data after form_valid action in django UpdateView?

Tags: django, view, model

I have successfully changed a particular field `net` in my object based on the quantity `qty` field with the following code.

```
class OrderDetailsProductEdit(UpdateView):
    model = OrdersPlaced
    fields = ['qty']
    template_name = 'backend/order-details-product-edit.html'
    success_url = '../../../'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.net = form.instance.qty * form.instance.price
        # order = Order.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['order_id'])
        # subtotal = OrdersPlaced.objects.filter(order=order).aggregate(Sum('net'))['net__sum']
        # order.subtotal = subtotal
        # order.save()
        return super(OrderDetailsProductEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

However, I am also trying to change the data in ANOTHER model. To be precise, I want the summation of all `net` values of a query and update the `subtotal` field in another table.

Please notice the commented out lines under `def form_valid`. I have no confusion that these lines work, but I need them to execute AFTER the current model is saved, as those are dependent on the value of the current model.

I don't find any errors other than that the `subtotal` field in ANOTHER model is calculated BEFORE the `net` field in the current model is saved. Thus, the total is a wrong answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, a bit unclear to me: why don't you just save the other model before saving this one?

Comment: @Wtower because the other model's data is the output of the data of this model. So the other model will contain wrong data if it is saved first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply move the instruction after calling super

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.net = form.instance.qty * form.instance.price
        redirect_url = super(OrderDetailsProductEdit, self).form_valid(form)
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['order_id'])
        subtotal = OrdersPlaced.objects.filter(order=order).aggregate(Sum('net'))['net__sum']
        order.subtotal = subtotal
        order.save()
        return redirect_url
```

or just do what calling `super` does (save model and redirect to `success_url`) by yourself

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.net = form.instance.qty * form.instance.price
        self.object = form.save()
        order = Order.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['order_id'])
        subtotal = OrdersPlaced.objects.filter(order=order).aggregate(Sum('net'))['net__sum']
        order.subtotal = subtotal
        order.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```